# How to use has_key with a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I Have an collection:
[a, b, c]
and i want verify if a hash contains some key of this collection

I try:

```
col = [a, b, c]
my_hash = {c => 1, f => 2, h => 3}

my_hash.has_key? col
=> false
```

but not work.
Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Iterate over `col` and check each.

No explanation required.

**2.** Use existing library functionality to do the same:

```
keys = [:a, :b, :c]
h = { c: 1, f: 2, h: 3 }
h.any? { |key, val| keys.include? key }
=> true
```

**3.** Set math:

```
h.keys & keys
=> [:c]
```

Then wrap it up to return true/false depending on which way you want things to read.

Comment: @ArnaldoJr Really ? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
my_hash.keys & col
# => [c]
```

[`&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-26) intersects the list of keys with the `col` array, returning only item in `col` which appear as keys in `my_hash`.

Another option - [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
my_hash.values_at(*col).compact
# => [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

But you can do:

```
my_hash.any? { |key,_| col.include?(key) }
```

Read it like - *Any key from `my_hash` included in `col` array*.